# Multiple android api calls using RxJava

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, rx-java

I have list of object which are sent as body for post request in each api call. All post request should be run in parallel. For each request it should notify  that either it is success or failure and once all post request completes it should notify. How to achieve this using rxjava

Please go through this code. Is this is the implementation?

```
    FlashSaleRetrofitService retrofitService = flashSaleProvider.createRetrofitService();
    FlashSale runningFlashSale = JumkeyApplication.getRunningFlashSale();

    List<Observable<Response<ClaimWrapper>>> wrapperResponseList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final CartProduct cartProduct : cartProducts) {

        final Claim claim = new Claim();

        Customer customer = customerDataProvider.getCustomer();
        claim.setCustomerId(String.valueOf(customer.getId()));
        claim.setEmail(customer.getEmail());
        claim.setMobileNumber(customer.getDefaultAddress().getPhone());
        claim.setProductId(Long.parseLong(cartProduct.getProductId()));
        claim.setVariantId(Long.parseLong(cartProduct.getVariantId()));
        claim.setQuantity(cartProduct.getQuantity());
        claim.setSaleId(runningFlashSale.getSaleId());

        wrapperResponseList.add(retrofitService.claimProduct(claim));
    }

    Observable.zip(wrapperResponseList, new FuncN<List<Claim>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Claim> call(Object... args) {
            return null;
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(new Action1<List<Claim>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<Claim> claims) {

                }
            })
            .compose(new Observable.Transformer<List<Claim>, Claim>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Claim> call(Observable<List<Claim>> listObservable) {
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Observer<Claim>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Claim claim) {

                }
            });
```

If this is not the right way, please suggest me how to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `Zip` method.

See the RxJava [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html).

Comment: Thank you, I ll look into the documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you want process results when all done.

```
Observable
        .zip(observables, new FuncN<List<Response<ClaimWrapper>>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> call(Object... args) {
                List<Response<ClaimWrapper>> result = new ArrayList<>(args.length);

                for (Object arg : args) {
                    result.add((Response<ClaimWrapper>) arg);
                }
                return result;
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Response<ClaimWrapper>>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Response<ClaimWrapper>> results) {

            }
        });
```

If you want process one by one when each it

```
Observable
        .merge(observables)
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<ClaimWrapper>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Response<ClaimWrapper> result) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. One problem with this is, if one request fails remaining requests are not executing. How to make them to execute even if previous request fails.

Comment: Am trying very hard but am not getting the expected result. Please anyone help me about this problem.

Comment: onError may be called only once. so each error in combined observable break all chain. The only way to receive other requests if something fail is suspend errors with onErrorResumeNext( ) or onErrorReturn( )